# Need Cursor Help or Alternative to Cursor use

Tags: sql

I have two tables.  One holds the demand qty each week for each record and the other holds the supply for each week but among several skus but same family.  What I need to do is to pull the demand value from the first table e.g. 7000 and pull the supply qty value from the first record and use it to fill the demand.  If the available qty >= demand, it will fill the demand for that week and stop.  If the supply is less e.g. 2000, it will take the amount available to fill demand and move to the next record and use that value and keep doing this until demand for that week is done or until it runs out of records.  Each time a value is used, it will decrease the amount of demand in the first table so it doesn't stay constant.
I am using a cursor that is not working right now because I think the demand is not being held and I might need a second cursor nested in the first.

Here is the code I have right now and would appreciate any help available:

```
DECLARE @sku nvarchar (255)
Declare @filled float
Declare @endinv float
Declare @demand float

select @demand = (select demand from testDemand where Date = '2014-11-30')


DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT
    sku,
    filleddemand,
    [ending inventory] 

FROM Test 
where [model family] = '4S' and Date = '2014-11-30' and program ='test tech' and [ending inventory] > '0'


OPEN MyCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO
    @sku,
    @filled,
    @endinv

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 

BEGIN

     if @endinv >= @demand
     SET @filled = @demand
    ELSE SET  @filled = @endinv



        update testDemand
        set Demand = Demand - t.filledsum
        FROM testdemand u INNER JOIN (select [model family], Date, sum(filleddemand) as filledsum
        from Test 
        group by [Model Family], Date) as t on t.[Model Family] = u.[Model Family] and u.Date = t.Date
        where  u.Date = '2014-11-30'

        UPDATE Test
        SET [Ending Inventory] = [Ending Inventory]- FilledDemand,
            Customers = 'testtech'
            from Test
            WHERE sku = @sku



FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO
    @sku,
    @filled,
    @endinv

End
CLOSE MyCursor
DEALLOCATE MyCursor
```

Comment: I don't have time right now to re-code what you posted, but have you tried to rewrite it as a MERGE INTO [YourTable] query?

Comment: I didn't know it had to contain a variable.  The update statement is needed to decrease the amount of demand left after a portion has been filled.

Comment: It doesn't have to contain a variable, but if nothing varies, you do the same thing as many times as the loops runs, probably giving you the same result (unless there are triggers or something)

Comment: Oh, wait, I'm being dumb.  You're decrementing demand: `set Demand = Demand - t.filledsum`.

Comment: Mikey Mouse, that is why I needed the cursor to have while demand > 0 but everytime I put that line of code in, I get an error

Comment: Still looking for some help on this.  Please wade in if you can help. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have solved this by using a temporary table.